# All possible combinations of a list with set of values

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix

I have three 'fields'

V0, V1 and V2

Each Field can be either 0, 1, or 2.

V0: allowed values [0, 1, 2]

V1: allowed values [0, 1, 2]

V2: allowed values [0, 1, 2]

Therefore, in order to generate each unique list of [V0, V1, V2], I should be seeing lists like:

[0,0,0], [0,0,1], [0,0,2], [0, 1, 0], [0, 2, 0], [1, 0, 0], [2, 0,0], [0, 1, 1] etc.

Finding every single unique list.

Is there a mathematical way to calculate how many potential combinations there could be? This in a way reminds me of Truth tables, but you can have more than two states on an input (0,1).

Is there a well known algorithm I can use to implement code that can create these lists? Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel!

Comment: This is known as a [cartesian product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product). The number is combinations is just the product of the number of allowed values, so `3*3*3 = 27`.

Comment: Implementing an algorithm that computes the cartesian product would might involve recursion. Using a built-in/library function that generates such a list would require checking documentation of the language of your choice. For example, Python has  [itertools.product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Answer (score 0):

You can find how many combinations with:

```
Combinations = V ^ N
```

- V is the number of values ​​that each variable can take
- N is the number of variables

Assuming that all variables adopt the same number of possible values.

To obtain the complete list you must go through each of the values ​​for each of the variables. You are going to have as many nested loops as there are values ​​of the variables.

Maybe you can implement some recursive function for it.